# Cordova FileReader overrides TypeScript FileReader

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova-plugins, ionic3

when i add the cordova-plugin-file-transfer plugin, I get the following error: `reader.addEventListener is not a function` .

This is because Cordova FileReader class overrides typescript FileReader.

How can i prevent this?.

How can i import native FileReader class ?

This is my function:

```
createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
    this.profilePicture = reader.result;
  }, false);
  if (image) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(image);
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you importing it *now*?

Comment: The file-transfer plugin with import `{ FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';` and i'm not importing `FileReader` class

Answer (score 0):

Rather than fighting with Typescript to use **FileReader of DOM**, following modification worked for me.

```
createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
  let reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = (event) => {
    if(reader.error){
      console.log(reader.error)
    } else {
      this.profilePicture = reader.result;
    }
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
```

I don't know why the need for such modifications. Everything was working properly. Since I installed Cordova File plugin, things started to break.